# How to use tuples as slice start:end values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, dimensions

I need to slice array with arbitrary dimensions by two tuples. I can use slicing, such as `a[1:3, 4:6]`. But what do i do if 1,3 and 4,6 are tuples?

While `a[(1, 3)]` works, I tried `a[(1, 3), (4, 6)]` and it didn't work, I think it ignores (4, 6). And I couldn't figure out how to make something like `a[ t1[0] : t1[1], t2[0] : t2[1] ]` work depending on how many dimensions there are.

I'd like something like `a[(1, 3):(4, 6)]`, that would also work for higher dimensions, e.g a[(1, 3, 2):(4, 6, 5)]

Comment: Try `slice(*tup))`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I am not quite sure how to do that. Here is what I did: a[slice( *(1,2) )]. It selected the second row, completely ignoring "2". I also tried a[slice( *((1, 2), (3, 5)) )] and it said TypeError: slice indices must be integers

Comment: If you have `t1 = (1, 3)` and `t2 = (4, 6)`, then `a[1:3, 4:6]` is equivalent to `a[slice(*t1), slice(*t2)]`.

Comment: Your last example would simply be `a[t1:t2]` for the same tuples.

Comment: `a[x:y:z]` is, by definition, `a[slice(x, y, z)]`. The `slice` type is how the extended slice syntax is implemented.

Comment: Is `a[(1, 3, 2):(4, 6, 5)]` supposed to translate to `a[1:3:2, 4:6:5]` or `a[1:4, 3:6, 2:5]`?  The key to all answers is that `a[b,c,d]` is actually `a[(b,c,d)]`, where the items in the tuple can be `slice` objects, numbers, or arrays.  Create that tuple however you find convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Extended slice syntax is implemented by the `slice` type. You can play with this using a simple toy class

```
class A:
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        print(k)
```

Then

```
>>> A()[1:3, 4:6]
(slice(1, 3, None), slice(4, 6, None))
```

`None` is the default 3rd argument if only two are given. So if you have tuples `(1, 3)` and `(4, 6)`, you can pass explicit `slice` objects created from them instead of using the extended slicing syntax.

```
>>> t1, t2 = (1,3), (4, 6)
>>> A()[slice(*t1), slice(*t2)]
(slice(1, 3, None), slice(4, 6, None))
```